# verb tense: Present Perfect vs Simple Past

Tags: tense

> Of course, I don't think you broke the window. The thought never even ....... my mind.

1. crossed
2. has crossed

Which one is correct? Are both possible here?

Comment: The way you're presented the alternatives is wrong. The two possibilities (both perfectly valid) are 1) *The thought never even crossed my mind* and 2) *The thought **has** never even crossed my mind*. That second (Perfect) version is extremely unlikely in your exact context, but it *might* work better in some context involving a longer timescale *(We've been married 20 years, and the thought that you might be gay has never occurred to me)*. But mostly, you should just avoid unnecessary Perfect verb forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - (1) The thought never even crossed my mind. [image: Green check mark, indicating normal form]
> - (2) The thought has never even crossed my mind. [image: Green check mark, indicating normal form]
> - (2A) The thought has never crossed my mind. [image: Green check mark, indicating normal form]
> - (3) The thought never even has crossed my mind.[image: Red X, indicating unacceptable form]

Sentence (1) is in very common usage. Indeed it is almost a fixed phrase. Sentence (2) using the prefect construction, is also used, and is quite aceptable, but is significantly less usual. The variant in sentence (2A) is significantly more common than the one in (2), although still less usual than (1). All of these are natural and acceptable uses in standard English.

Sentence (3) is not natural. The auxiliary "has" is not commonly placed after modifiers in this way..